# referencing the value of a radio button when clicking a submit button jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

```
    <form action="loginServlet" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action">
    <p><input type="radio" name="grain" value="product/1858C">Avangard Malz Premium Caramel 55 Lb 8L (like C10)</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="grain" value="product/1860C">Avangard Malz Premium Caramel 55 Lb 30L (like C30)</p>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class = "button">
    </form>
```

How do I reference the radio button that is checked, in JSP?
Something like:
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
But the parameter has to be the checked radio button.

Comment: Don't you want request.getParameter("grain")?

Comment: Oh I see. So that will return the checked radio button value as a string?

Comment: @Peter and what are you expecting to return ??

Comment: I need the string that is in the radio button's value parameter, so I can reference it and pull it from one mysql table and assign it to another mysql table. The value in the radio button is the key for the mysql table

Comment: you can get the value of radio button with servlet that what you want ?
if it is checked you will have the value=''product/1858C '' if not check the value =null

Comment: @Peter so you want to get the "Avangard Ma..." value isn't it

Comment: Yes. Create a string  that contains the value from the radio button. I kinda know how to handle it in the servlet, but I've never done the referencing from a radio  button. Thanks for everyone who downvoted. That brings me to total of -13. My questions really must suck.

Comment: @PacMan, I need the string literal that is in value="product/1858C"

Comment: what do you mean with referencing from a radio button ? clarify what you want you say i can do it with servlet where is the problem then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one it may help you sure even if ti not much optimal but it will handle it

```
    String finalResult = null;
    String x = request.getParameter('grain');
    if(x.equals("product/1858C")){
       finalResult = "Avangard Malz Premium Caramel 55 Lb 8L (like C10)";
     }else{
       finalResult = "Avangard Malz Premium Caramel 55 Lb 30L (like C30)";
}
```

and then you can use the finalResult string as you want in your servlet 
if there is any problem with it let me know

Comment: he say  I need the string literal that is in value="product/1858C"

Comment: @Taha yes i understand what he want and he will know what my answer will do

Answer (score 0):

Use request.getParameter("grain") and You will get the value of the checked Radio button.